# Waiting until last debugger command completes

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, smali

When I debug smali with Smalidea on idea or Android Studio, I get a mistake say Smalidea throws an uncaught `NullPointerException`, and in the variables it says "Waiting until last debugger command completes", but 20 minutes later, nothing happens.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve it ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in smalidea :) https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/issues is the place to report bugs.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I had a different fix that solved the same issue, and that might be useful for others. I had a tonn of old breakpoints hanging around. Once I deleted all, all my problems with Android Studio went away, "Waiting until last debugger command completes", forever "Collection data...", and the IDE was much more snappy as well.

Just goto:
Run > View Breakpoints... and delete the breakpoints you do not need.

Comment: Problem may be some how related to the breakpoints. I am getting it when i debug a BufferedRead statement with a breakpoint on this line and going f7 ( step into ). It stop on "Waiting unit..." and step into does not go further. But when removing breakpoint it throws exception. Solution ? not know

Answer (score 1):

Ok,I can answer my question now.It's because of too many registers in watches frame.When I delete all registers,it goes ok.But how can I debug it with many register?

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me.

1.Force stop app if its already installed.
2. build > Clean Project