# Are there other options to resolve "Waiting until last debugger command completes", "Collecting data", or the debug hanging?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, freeze

**Problem:** During debugging, I'm not able to see what is contained in my `ArrayList`or be able to step pass it. At times, I cannot even add to the `ArrayList` when debugging (see image below) This appears to be a serious issue for quite some time based upon researching forums on the web.

Using:

- Intellij 2021.1.1
- Java 11
- Android 29
- Gradle 4.1.3

**What I have tried:** I've tried all the common workarounds based upon the links below found here at stackoverflow and other forums. Updating any of my sources above have no impact. I could not even find on JetBrains any resolution that wasn't still outstanding. Many posted there with no resolution I found. I think I even found a post started in 2015 and still had others asking for resolution in 2020.

I think these 3 links describe all the workarounds I tried and are common. For some they work, for others they didn't. I found that disabling the "Enable ToString() object view" worked briefly, then I started having the same issue again.

[Intellij debugger gets stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863400/intellij-debugger-gets-stuck)

[Waiting until last debugger command completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863159/waiting-until-last-debugger-command-completes)

[Waiting until... Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290304/how-to-solve-waiting-until-last-debugger-command-completes-stuck-in-android-st)

So again, the issue is two-fold: 1) I can't access the data, and 2) I can't step over it either if it is to follow breakpoint... and I cannot F9 pass it either.

[[image: Freezing when just wanting to add to an ArrayList]

Comment: Have you checked recommendations in [slow performance or hangups when starting debugger and stepping](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/categories/200793669-General) post?

Comment: @Andrey Yes. I had found those same recommendations in one or more of the links above.